# What is localhost.pharos from Netstat?

Tags: macos, network, hosts

Over past week, netstat reflects an established connection to localhost.pharos.

Googled [Pharos](http://www.pharos.com) and it's a software which enables printing services at Universities/Enterprises.

***Any ideas why connection is constant at each login?***

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp6       0      0  localhost.pharos       localhost.49437        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.49437        localhost.pharos       ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.krb524       localhost.49436        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.49436        localhost.krb524       ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 2):

pharos and krb524 are both just guesses about network services, based on the service <-> port number listings in /etc/services; in this case I'm fairly sure they're both *wrong* guesses, so just think of them as identifiers for port numbers 4443 and 4444 respectively. To  find out what's really going on, you need to find out what programs are connecting via those ports. You can do this with the `lsof` commands, like this:

```
sudo lsof -i:pharos -i:krb524
```

(you'll need to enter your admin password for `sudo` to get root access.) In the output, the important bits are the first two columns, which list the program ("command") names and process IDs of the processes that are using these ports. If the program name doesn't tell you what's going on, you can use `ps` and/or Activity Monitor to investigate those processes in more detail.

EDIT: If I'm reconstructing the `lsof` output correctly, it looks like this:

```
COMMAND   PID          USER  FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
collabd    237 _teamsserver  7u   IPv6 0x7da9dd76981ec947      0t0  TCP localhost:pharos->localhost:50603 (ESTABLISHED
ruby       323 _teamsserver  31u  IPv6 0x7da9dd76981eeb47      0t0  TCP localhost:50602->localhost:krb524 (CLOSE_WAIT)
xcsbuildd 6943 _teamsserver  8u   IPv6 0x7da9dd76981ecd87      0t0  TCP localhost:50603->localhost:pharos (ESTABLISHED)
```

Those all look like components of OS X Server -- I'm not very familiar with the details, but `collabd` is a background process relating to "collaborative services" parts of OS X server, and the _teamserver user ID is used for those services.  From comparing to my server, it looks like the `ruby` script handles notifications, and `xcsbuildd` is probably the Xcode build server. Apparently, they all talk to each other over ports 4443 and 4444.

Comment: Output from that command:

Comment: COMMAND    PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
***collabd    237 _teamsserver***    7u  IPv6 0x7da9dd76981ec947      0t0  TCP localhost:pharos->localhost:50603 (ESTABLISHED
***ruby       323 _teamsserver***   31u  IPv6 0x7da9dd76981eeb47      0t0  TCP localhost:50602->localhost:krb524 (CLOSE_WAIT)
xcsbuildd ***6943 _teamsserver***    8u  IPv6 0x7da9dd76981ecd87      0t0  TCP localhost:50603->localhost:pharos (ESTABLISHED)